# Chrome extension: Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the url of the current tab. However, I keep getting the folling error

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
at chrome-extension://haencpbflmfmghcblmadiohldhpidihf/background.js:3:25
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "x",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "y!",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
"manifest_version": 2}
```

background.js

```
console.log("h")
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    console.log(tabs[0].url);
});
```

I have tried replacing tabs permission with the activeTab but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: The error message means `tabs` is an empty array i.e. no tabs were found at the time you invoked query(). Your background script is persistent so it runs at browser start when there are no tabs yet. What is your actual final goal, how/where do you want to use this url?

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm trying to get URL from the tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm It's weird because when I load the extension for the first time, it displays me the extension URL. But when I go to say, google.com and refresh the console it displays the above error

Comment: 1) When you load the extension for the first time the background script runs at that moment and naturally it finds the tabs. 2) The background script is not related to any sites, it runs in a hidden background page which has its [own devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029). 3) To read `url` of a tab its URL pattern should be added to `"permissions"` in manifest.json or `"<all_urls>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome.tabs.query is meant for v3 of manifest. You have to use chrome.tabs.getSelected while using v2.

For manifest v3, see: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query